# How to dispose a Poller with a blocked socket?

Tags: c#, zeromq, dispose, netmq

I have single socket, which is blocked on sending the frame and I would like to dispose poller ( and everything related to it ). However, I cannot do it -- calling dispose on socket throws an exception, and calling dispose on poller completely blocks.

Please note, I am using `SendFrame` and I could use `TrySendFrame`, but the purpose of this example is to actually block the socket and find a way how to clean up everything.

Example:

```
private Program()
{
    const string address = "tcp://localhost:5000";

    var socket = new DealerSocket();
    socket.Options.SendHighWatermark = 1;
    socket.Options.Identity = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    socket.Connect(address);

    var poller = new NetMQPoller();
    poller.Add(socket);
    socket.SendReady += OnSendReady;
    poller.RunAsync();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Disposing");
    poller.Dispose(); // get stuck on this one
    Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
}

private void OnSendReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("0");
    e.Socket.SendFrame("hello");
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    e.Socket.SendFrame("hello"); // this will block
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

*Tested with NetMQ 3.3.3.4 (my primary version for now) and 4.0.0.1.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**) Always zeroize `ZMQ_LINGER`. **Always**. Right upon a `socket` instantiation, so as to prevent otherwise inadvertent blocking on graceful termination `{ .close() | .term() }` operations ( be it a controlled or un-controlled activation of termination ops ( as you already have faced it ) ).

**2**) Avoid blocking designs. **Principally.** Each blocking state creates a state, in which all your code is out-of-control. Got it?

Comment: Thank you, but AFAIK `Linger` is zero by default. Now I wonder if it would be better for poller to throw exception (like socket) in case of such clash. Anyway, this solves my question.

Comment: ZMQ_LINGER was not zero on default since ZeroMQ was born. Yes, recent API has changed that, but a professional distributed system design ought exhibit all pre-cautions explicitly ( who knows where your code will run & what API version will be actually present on all the remote localhosts, that are out of question outside of your zone of enforce-able {version|release|configuration}-management control procedures, right? Old assembler sources had a great practice to always start with #ASSUME NOTHING ;o) )